# How to detect change on persistent memory-mapped file in .Net core (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dllimport, map-files

The title is the question it is.

Legend:

1. Project A = .Net Core project
2. Project B = Legacy C++ project
3. MMF = Persistent Memory-mapped file

**Detailed question description:**

I currently working on (PROJECT A) which using [DllImport] to import native library which written on C++ to access the MMF.

I have another legacy application (PROJECT B) continuously updating    that MMF.

---

> What I want is, if there is some change in specific section of the
>   MMF. We trigger the function in project A.

---

If you have any clue, please help. Thank you

Comment: You need to use IPC and synchronisation. Which makes one wonder why you don't use a message passing approach instead of shared memory. What made you choose shared memory?

Comment: Windows can track changes to files, but it won't notify you of what specific bytes have changed. You could use a combination of notifications (`FIleWatcher` et al) combined with reading the relevant parts of the file, or per David you'll need to actually implement specific mechanisms to signal the change beyond just changing the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan since my legacy application using MMF as storage. And I don't have authorize to change the architecture of it

Comment: By the time that you've implemented the message passing and synchronisation, you may as well do it all that way